# Colaboratory importing .py files error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I mounted Google drive in Colaboratory and set path to the drive/.
It seems that the path is set correctly, however when I run my code, the files can't  be read. I am quite sure that proc_data_lib.py is a pythonfile instead of zip file and the first few lines of that python file is in the second picture
[Error Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cor8.png)

[File:proc_data_lib.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cds4z.png)

ERROR INFO: File "drive/ECMLDeepAudio-Master/lib/proc_data_lib.py", line 1
    PK�����rpL^�2'���'������mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK�����rpL/�4z���������Thumbnails/thumbnail.png�PNG
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it is a zip file not a python file

Comment: Try renaming your proc_data_lib.py to proc_data_lib.zip and unzip it

Comment: proc_data_lib.py is a python file and the path is correct.

Comment: Post errors as text instead of images please

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the file is not *just* a text file -- from the error message, it seems to be a custom format of type `oasis.opendocument.text`, which looks to be an [OpenOffice file](https://www.openoffice.org/framework/documentation/mimetypes/mimetypes.html). Were you writing the file with something like OpenOffice?

Switching to a vanilla text file should fix things.